# How to update the junction table with user's role in Adonis

Tags: javascript, mysql, many-to-many, junction-table, adonis.js

I have a database with three tables: `users`, `games` and `game_user`. `users`and `games` have a many to many relationship with `game_user` as its junction table

The table `game_user` has only three columns (other than `id`): `game_id`, `user_id` and `game_admin`.

The idea is that `user` can be a regular user in a `game`, or an `admin`. I would store the values `0` for the former and `1` for the later, for example.

I'm not sure how to do it in Adonis. I have read the documentation and maybe I should create a `pivotModel`, but I'm not sure how to do it (or IF I should do it for that matter).

I tried the following:

```
class GameUserSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('game_user', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.integer('user_id').unsigned().index('user_id')
      table.integer('game_id').unsigned().index('game_id')
      table.integer('game_admin').unsigned().index('game_admin')
      table.foreign('user_id').references('users.id')
                                            .onDelete('cascade')
      table.foreign('game_id').references('games.id')
                                            .onDelete('cascade')
    })
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('game_user')
  }
}
```

Now when I add games I usually do with the following code:

```
const newGame = await Game.create(gameData)
await user.games().attach([newGame.id])
```

But that only updates the junction table with `user_id`, obviously, not with the user's role.

So my question is: Is my migration file correct or is there a better way? Also how can I update the junction table when creating a game?

Comment: Pivot-table tag is for transposing rows to columns, not an alias for junction tables. Some ORMs refer to junction tables as pivot tables confusing many developers. Pls read the tag descriptions before using them.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that, but I think the tag could be updated, or a new one created, since "Some ORMs refer to junction tables as pivot tables". Just my two cents, but it changes nothing in the question (except some word choices. Thanks for the correction though.

Comment: Or you could ask the people behind your chosen ORM to stop referring to junction tables as pivot tables... The pivot-table tag definition is just fine, adding this reference would confuse users. You managed to find the right tag for your question after being prompted.

Answer (score 0):

To update the extra attributes of association table you should be using pivot models
here is something you can use as a callback to attach method

```
await user.games().attach(games, (row) => {
   row.game_admin = 1 
})
```

Comment: One more thing for pivot models the schema would have to be changed, the table name would become game_users in this case